# R shiny and ggplot2: How to make border of geom_col transparent?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, transparency, geom-col

I want to make the border of geom_col transparent. It works when only using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

dataToPlot <- data.frame(Freq = c(0.0000000, 0.7092199, 1.4184397, 2.1276596, 2.8368794), 
                          variable = rep('A',5), value = c(43089.76, 62923.17, 35446.15, 29553.76, 22433.08))

p <- ggplot( dataToPlot , aes(x=Freq, y = value, group = variable   )  ) +  #
  # geom_bar(stat = "bin") fill = variable, 
  geom_col( mapping = aes(col = variable, fill = variable), colour = F,  alpha = 0.2, orientation = "x", position = "dodge") + 
  # scale_linetype(aes(linetype = 0))
  guides(color = FALSE)

dev.new(); p
```

However, the exact same code with shiny gives the error: "Error: invalid color name 'FALSE'"

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

dataToPlot <- data.frame(Freq = c(0.0000000, 0.7092199, 1.4184397, 2.1276596, 2.8368794), 
                          variable = rep('A',5), value = c(43089.76, 62923.17, 35446.15, 29553.76, 22433.08))

ui <- fluidPage( 
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow( 
    column(8,
           plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot( dataToPlot , aes(x=Freq, y = value, group = variable   )  ) +  #
      # geom_bar(stat = "bin") fill = variable, 
      geom_col( mapping = aes(col = variable, fill = variable), colour = F,  alpha = 0.2, orientation = "x", position = "dodge") + 
      # scale_linetype(aes(linetype = 0))
      guides(color = FALSE)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes you are doing.

First, you forgot to mention that you are also using the packages `shinyjs` and `plotly`.

Second, you are using `renderPlotly` in the server part, but calling `plotOutput` in the ui. The correct is `plotlyOutput` in the ui, since you want a plotly graphic.

The other thing is: since you want a plotly type of graphic, you have to transform your ggplot graphic `p` to a plotly one. Therefore, you should add `ggplotly(p)` into the server part.

Finally, in order to solve the problem with the borders, you should use `colour = NA` instead of `colour = FALSE`. The second way works with ggplot2, but not with plotly. I do not know exactly why. Perhaps someone could clarify this.

So, your code should look like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(plotly)

dataToPlot <- data.frame(Freq = c(0.0000000, 0.7092199, 1.4184397, 2.1276596, 2.8368794),
                         variable = rep('A',5), 
                         value = c(43089.76, 62923.17, 35446.15, 29553.76, 22433.08))

ui <- fluidPage( 
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow( 
    column(8,
           plotlyOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(dataToPlot , aes(x=Freq, y = value, group = variable)) +
      geom_col(mapping = aes(col = variable, fill = variable), colour = NA,  alpha = 0.2, orientation = "x", position = "dodge") + 
      guides(color = FALSE)

    ggplotly(p)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```